# How to keep an HTML element in view during CSS transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have a `<div>` that I toggle between visible/invisible by transitioning it's `max-height` property between `0px` and `1000px`. It works well. However if the top of the `<div>` is, say, only 200px above the bottom of the window, then the transition will extend the bottom of div to outside (below) the viewable area, and the scroll bar appears and slightly shrinks, indicating that there is more available space to scroll down to.

I want to automatically keep the `<div>` element always in view, having the scroll position of the document follow the bottom of the `<div>` smoothly so that as its height increases, the scroll position increases at the same speed. How can I keep this HTML element in view during the CSS transition in this case?

A perfect solution would be to somehow specify that the element should have relative positioning to the rest of the document for it's original position, but it's bottom-border should never be < 0px from the bottom of the window (I know of no way to do this in CSS, because you have to commit to one `position` property or another).

Other scroll examples I've found through googling all seem to have an assumption that the total document height remains the same (e.g. http://wibblystuff.blogspot.com/2014/04/in-page-smooth-scroll-using-css3.html) however in my case the document height changes during the transition (because almost always in my case if the `<div>` is only 200px above the bottom of the window then it is also at the very end of the document.

Also: The only browser I need to support is the latest version of Chrome, so maybe there are some new features there that I'm not aware of that can help?

Comment: This is too hard to follow without a Codepen example or something...

Comment: You can fix the <div> at bottom of page. Its hight then will grow up to the top of the page. You want that? And what shall happen when it  reaches the top of window and its height increases more? It then sneaks out of document top and the outer part is not visible?